# Why on some computers I don't receive TLS Alert to close the connection?

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, aws-api-gateway

I have a program that opens an HTTPS connection with keep-alive, performs an HTTP request, does something else and then tries to perform a second HTTP request using the same connection.

If more than 5 minutes have elapsed, the server closes the connection by sending TLS Alert and the connection moves to CLOSE_WAIT state. The HTTPS client detects that the connection is bad (it uses poll to check) and opens a new connection instead.

On a few different computers, this works every time.

In two environments it fails every time. After the server has forgotten about the connection, the client still thinks it is in ESTABLISHED state and the client sends the second HTTP request using the same socket and waits for the ACK. The ACK never comes, the client re-transmits and eventually the client throws a timeout exception. The client never received any indication from the server that the connection is closed. I've checked using Wireshark.

The client is written in python (using a session object from the requests library) and runs on Linux in a cloud VM and the server is AWS API Gateway, but I don't know if it matters.

What could make the server not send anything when closing the connection, or alternatively what could make the client not receive the message from the server about the connection closing?

Comment: The ACK should never come. What should come is an RST.

Comment: Of course, because the server already forgot about the connection, I understand that.